# Creating a multidimensional array (D>5) from a dictionary..?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a multidimensional array using vectors of different lengths to map out the 'process space' of a problem. I've started by storing values in keys of a dictionary:

```
d = {'width' : [1,2,3,5,3,5,3],
 'height' : [1,2,3,5,5,3],
 'length' : [1,3,3,7,8,0,0,7,2,3,6,3,2,3],
 'composition' : [1,2,3,5,5,3],
 'year' : [7,5,3,2,1,6,4,9,11],
 'efficiency' : [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]}
```

Is it possible to use these keys to construct a multidimensional (6D) matrix of size

`(7,6,14,6,9,9)`? (That is, each dictionary key would be represented as a separate dimension of the final array)

EDIT: 
   I would like to use this matrix as a means of looking at a cross section of the data. For example, I would like to be able to say, "Here are all the efficiency values as a function of 'Length', given:

```
width = 4
height = 2
composition = 3
year = 7
```

Comment: A matrix of size `(7,6,14,6,9,9)` would have 7*7*6*14*6*9*9 entries.

Comment: @imp9 -- Edited my original question to answer your question.

Comment: Do you have enough values to fill a 6 dimensional matrix?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are naming the columns as dimensions.

Since you have indexes and data, use pandas DataFrames

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
d = {'width' : [1,2,3,5,3,5,3],
 'height' : [1,2,3,5,5,3],
 'length' : [1,3,3,7,8,0,0,7,2,3,6,3,2,3],
 'composition' : [1,2,3,5,5,3],
 'year' : [7,5,3,2,1,6,4,9,11],
 'efficiency' : [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]}
```

Since there is missing data you need a intermediate step until you can turn it into a DataFrame.

```
intermediate=dict()
for x in d:
    intermediate[x]=Series(d[x])

data=DataFrame(intermediate)
```

then you can query data using normal pandas syntax.

```
data[data.length>5]

    composition  efficiency  height  length  width  year
3             5           3       5       7      5     2
4             5           5       5       8      3     1
7           NaN          21     NaN       7    NaN     9
10          NaN         NaN     NaN       6    NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

### Basic principle

The simples and most efficient way would be using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/).

```
d = {'width' : [1,2,3,5,3,5,3],
     'height' : [1,2,3,5,5,3],
     'length' : [1,3,3,7,8,0,0,7,2,3,6,3,2,3],
     'composition' : [1,2,3,5,5,3],
     'year' : [7,5,3,2,1,6,4,9,11],
     'efficiency' : [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]}
```

You need an order of your names:

```
names = ['width' ,'height', 'length' ,'composition', 'year','efficiency']
```

Import NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
```

Find the shape:

```
shape = tuple(len(d[name]) for name in names)
```

`shape` is:

```
(7, 6, 14, 6, 9, 9)
```

Create an array of zeros:

```
lookup = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.uint16)
```

I use very small unsigned integers to save space. You can use larger numbers if needed:

Now `lookup` can be used like this:

```
>>> lookup[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
0
>>> lookup[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] = 12
>>> lookup[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
12
```

Lookup all values for `efficiency`:

```
>>> lookup[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, :]
array([12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], dtype=uint16)
```

All values for `year` and `efficiency`:

```
>>> lookup[0, 0, 0, 0, :, :]
array([[12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint16)
```

### Useful class

For convenience, wrap into a class:

```
class Lookup(object):
    def __init__(self, dims, dtype=np.uint16):
        self.names = [item[0] for item in dims]
        self.shape = [item[1] for item in dims]
        self.repr = np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=dtype)

    def _make_loc(self, coords):
        return [coords.get(name, slice(None)) for name in self.names]

    def get_value(self, coords):
        return self.repr.__getitem__(self._make_loc(coords))

    def set_value(self, coords, value):
        return self.repr.__setitem__(self._make_loc(coords), value)
```

Specify the dimensions:

```
dims = [('width', 7),
        ('year', 9),
        ('composition', 6),
        ('height', 6),
        ('efficiency', 9),
        ('length', 14)]
```

Make an instance:

```
lookup = Lookup(dims)
```

Set a value:

```
coords1 = {'width': 3,
          'height': 1,
          'composition': 2,
          'year': 6, 
          'length': 3}

lookup.set_value(coords1, 11)
```

Get a value back:

```
coords2 = {'width': 3,
          'height': 1,
          'composition': 2,
          'year': 6}

lookup.get_value(coords2)
```

Gives you :

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint16)
```

Comment: @A.Pung is this what you want?